# User is typing notification using SMACK api in JAVA

Tags: java, smack

I'm trying to implement this module where one displays that the user is typing when he is typing a message. I'm new to this thing so please ignore silly mistakes if found. I checked out the documentation and this what I came up with in the code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class ChatBoard extends JFrame implements MessageListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static String username, password;
    static XMPPConnection connection;
    private JTextField textField;
    static JLabel board = new JLabel("<html>");
    static Chat chat;
    String message;
    static String to;
    static boolean flag = true;
    ChatState status;

    public class typingStatus implements ChatStateListener {

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(Chat arg0, ChatState arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(arg0.getParticipant() + " is " + arg1.name());

        }

    }

    public void sendChat(String msg) {
        //send chat code

    }

    public ChatBoard(String user, String pass) {

        setVisible(true);
        username = user;
        password = pass;
        //JFrame Creation code
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus();

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus();

            }

            private void changeStatus() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (textField.getText().isEmpty() == false) {
                    try {
                        ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection)
                                .setCurrentState(ChatState.composing, chat);
                    } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection)
                                .setCurrentState(ChatState.inactive, chat);
                    } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus();

            }
        });

        //JFrame creation code



        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                "prc.p1.im", 5222, "prc.p1.im");

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

        try {
            connection.connect();

        } catch (XMPPException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Not Connected. Error :" + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            connection.login(username, password);

        } catch (XMPPException e) {

            flag = false;

            textField.setVisible(false);
            sendButton.setVisible(false);

            info.setText("Invalid Login!");

            welcomeLabel.setText("Invalid user!");

        }



        connection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {

            public void chatCreated(final Chat chat,
                    final boolean createdLocally) {

                chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, final Message message) {
                        try {
                            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    String sender = message.getFrom();
                                    if (username.compareTo("shraz") == 0)
                                        sender = "h";
                                    else
                                        sender = "t";

                                    if (message != null
                                            || message.getBody() != "")
                                        board.setText(board.getText()
                                                + "<br> <font color=red>"
                                                + sender
                                                + " </font>:<font color=black> "
                                                + message.getBody() + "</font>");
                                    URL url = getClass().getResource(
                                            "resource/ultrakill_ultimate.wav");
                                    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
                                    clip.play();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });

            }

        });



    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {

        //Displaying message code here

    }

}
```

The Chat is taking place bidirectionally well. However, on running this code I get the following Exception whenever I type in anything:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Arguments cannot be null.
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.ChatStateManager.setCurrentState(ChatStateManager.java:118)
    at ChatBoard$2.changeStatus(ChatBoard.java:165)
    at ChatBoard$2.insertUpdate(ChatBoard.java:156)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:202)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:749)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:708)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:670)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(JTextComponent.java:1379)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:876)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1661)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1908)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:752)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1017)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:889)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:717)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4730)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Any comments on how to implement this module or what mistake I'm doing?

LINE 165 :

```
ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection).setCurrentState(ChatState.composing, chat);
```

LINE 156:

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus(); //<-line 156

            }
```

Comment: Hey, Have you got fix? Please suggest me , i am also trying to get typing status.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the following providers into your application?

```
ProviderManager pm = ProviderManager.getInstance();
pm.addExtensionProvider("active","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
pm.addExtensionProvider("composing","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider()); 
pm.addExtensionProvider("paused","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
pm.addExtensionProvider("gone","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
```

Once you add these providers, you will be able to read those states.

I will recommend you to add and initialize these providers when you first connect your remote server.

Hope this may help

Answer (score 2):

The variable `chat` does not get initialized and therefore is `null`.

Comment: For testing purpose, I initialized the chat as follows `chat=connection.getChatManager().createChat("userx@prc.p1.im",this);` . The errors have gone. However it is repeatedly sending null messages whenever something is type. I'm not getting any console output for typing as I have coded. The typingStatus is not detecting the state it seems. Does the logic in the code sound ok?

Comment: @user1435686: That's a bit hard to tell. There is a lot of unimplemented stuff...

Comment: @Lucas Hoepner May you provide me any source code for that? please thank

Answer (score 0):

MessageEventManager mem = new MessageEventManager(mConnection);
 mem.sendComposingNotification(mBuddyName, mMsgid);